# Receiving gzip with Flask

Tags: python, curl, flask, gzip

I'm trying to receive a gzipped JSON file from an HTTP POST to Flask (v0.10). I feel there may be some extra data posted that needs stripping out before trying to open the gzip.

Here's the code I have:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, abort
import gzip, StringIO
app = Flask(__name__)

# Handle posted data
@app.route('/', methods = ['POST'])
def post_gzip():

    # Check for a supported media type
    if (request.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/x-gzip'):

        file = request.data
        f = gzip.open(file, 'rb')        

        return f;

    else:
        # 415 Unsupported Media Type
        abort(415)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

I'm posting a zipped JSON file to Flask with cURL as follows:

```
curl -X POST -d @test.json.gz http://127.0.0.1:5000/ -H "Content-Type:application/x-gzip" -H "Content-Encoding:gzip"
```

And the error I'm receiving is:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte
```

It seems like Flask can't see the received data as being a gz file. Perhaps **request.data** isn't the right thing to use even.

Could some kind person point me in the right direction with this one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You import `StringIO` but never actually utilize it and feed a string to `gzip.open` which requires a filename. The error you're getting is from `gzip` trying to decode the filename to Unicode before attempting to open it.
The following utilizes StringIO to make a file-like object that can be used by gzip:

```
...
fakefile = StringIO.StringIO(request.data) # fakefile is now a file-like object thta can be passed to gzip.GzipFile:
uncompressed = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=fakefile, mode='r')
return uncompressed.read()
...
```

Edit:
I've refactored the code below and put relevant comments for a better understanding of what is going on:

```
from flask import Flask, request
import gzip, StringIO

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods = ['POST'])
def my_function():

    # `request.data` is a compressed string and `gzip.GzipFile`
    # doesn't work on strings. We use StringIO to make it look
    # like a file with this:
    fakefile = StringIO.StringIO(request.data)

    # Now we can load the compressed 'file' into the 
    # `uncompressed` variable. While we're at it, we
    # tell gzip.GzipFile to use the 'rb' mode
    uncompressed = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=fakefile, mode='rb')

    # Since StringIOs aren't real files, you don't have to 
    # close the file. This means that it's safe to return
    # its contents directly:
    return uncompressed.read()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

Comment: Now I'm getting this error: **IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: '\x1f\x8b\x08\x08\xae\x8e\x
dcT\x02\xffflask_test.json\x1f\xc0\xb5\xb6\xfb\x072\xe8\x1d\xb4>\x08\x17@\xcd\xd
9\x88L\xceN\xe0\x82\x86d\x9e\x8dh\xb1\x84\xfd\x04)\xe1\xd1\x81\x91\x9b\x07\xe1&0
Q?\x1a\x111V\xcd\xe5\xa7\xf5\xef\xa7E\x9b\x06\x11z\xeb\xc6\xa4\xff\xd1F\xd97\xbf
\x94\xe2y!\xe8q\xb6d\x94\x15\xb7\x94\xddf\xe5\x9c\xbfp\xc6\xe8/>`\x8c?'**

Comment: `from flask import Flask, request
import gzip, StringIO

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/', methods = ['POST'])
def my_function():

    fakefile = StringIO.StringIO(request.data)    
    uncompressed  = gzip.GzipFile(fakefile.read())
    file_content = f.read()
    f.close()
    
    return file_content

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.debug = True
    app.run()`

Comment: If I change `uncompressed = gzip.GzipFile(fakefile.read())` to `uncompressed = gzip.GzipFile(fakefile)` I get **TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, instance found**

Comment: Please read the following: https://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html#gzip.GzipFile

gzip.GzipFile takes a file-like argument with the fileobj named argument. You're passing it as a filename by omitting the parameter. The 3rd line in my answer shows the correct usage. gzip.GzipFile(fakefile) is incorrect in your use case.

Comment: Thanks for the support Iskren, my mistake for omitting **fileobj**. I'm now having a CRC check problem. I'll keep at it. Thanks again. `IOError: CRC check failed 0x2fe8c670 != 0x0L`

Answer (score 17):

For Python 3, I would just use `gzip.decompress(request.data)` which returns a decompressed string.

It's just a convenient shorthand function, added 8 years ago :)

If you want to take a look at the code, you can find it [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.7/Lib/gzip.py#L538).

**2019 edit**: wrote a simple [flask extension](https://github.com/ronlut/flask-inflate) you can use in your app.

Comment: Nice, thanks for that flask extension! Just wondering: do you experienced any performance implication? We have an endpoint which accepts a plain JSON object which contains a property with gzip encoded string. If this string is gzip decoded within the endpoint, performance is amazing. When doing it as a decorator with your extension, throughput is drastically reduced (in case it has to kick in). Any ideas?

Comment: For whoever interested, I continued the discussion with @boesing [here](https://github.com/ronlut/flask-inflate/issues/3)

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer is correct for Python 2, but just in case you're trying this with Python 3, you need to use BytesIO instead of StringIO:

```
compressed_data = io.BytesIO(request.data)
text_data = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=compressed_data, mode='r')
```